# I am unable to connect my database(in Xampp server) to my Java GUI project in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, localhost

Pls tell me how to resolve it, I have tried many things. But still I keep getting

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. 
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

If I comment out my DB code, then my project works fine

Here is my code

```
public class IdCard{
static Statement s;
static Connection con;
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    try{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/mini";
            String user = "root";
            String pass = "";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
            s = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Db connected!");
        }catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        
        public void run() {
            try {
                IdCard window = new IdCard();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the port number correct? `8080` doesn't looks correct. If you didn't change the default port on MySQL, try `3306` as port minber.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam sir ,I have checked it....even in Xampp server it shows localhost:8080